# NixOS, Haskell, opengl : problems with building and running openGL programs

Tags: haskell, opengl, nixos

I'm experiencing a problem with GL on NixOS: the problem seems to be old, but there is still no straightforward solution yet in 2017!

I'm trying to build a Haskell program using the `Gloss` library. I have installed `gloss` and everything it needs using the `nix-shell -p mesa` and it seems to be properly build and istalled (using `cabal install`). However if I build the program in the same `nix-shell` it doesn't work:

```
$ nix-shell -p mesa_glu

[nix-shell:]$ ghc --make -O2 SnakePar.hs
Linking SnakePar ...

[nix-shell:]$ ./SnakePar 
SnakePar: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

While working outside of a `nix-shell` the linking stage failes:

```
$ ghc --make -O2 SnakePar.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( SnakePar.hs, SnakePar.o )
Linking SnakePar ...
/nix/store/<hash>-binutils-2.27/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
/nix/store/<hash>-binutils-2.27/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

This happens even though I have manually installed the `glu` library via `nix-env -iA`.

```
$ nix-env -q
cabal-install-1.24.0.0
ghc-8.0.1
glu-9.0.0
```

I have tried using `freeglut` or `mesa` in the same manner, but none of these (or even all together) didn't work.

What am I missing?

This question is relevant but it doesn't help: [nixos + haskell + opengl (prerequisites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310973/nixos-haskell-opengl-prerequisites)

**Solution:** After switching to stack everything works.

Comment: Can you post a repository so I can reproduce?

Comment: @iElectric, It could be any Gloss MWE (just display a circle, for example), or something more interesting, like RosettaCode [snake game](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Snake).

Comment: After having read this page carefully, I'm still facing the described problem when using stack/nixos/gloss . I'd highly appreciate if someone could upload a minimal working example to a github repo. This would be really nice.

Comment: @AntonHarald, for a repository that doesn't have those linker errors, have a look at https://github.com/turion/rhine/tree/develop/rhine-gloss. But it has another puzzling error, this time related to GLUT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *just* fixed this, after three days of, well, being another not-happy Arch-user-until-last-week: try adding `freeglut` to the `nix-shell` environment, i.e. use `nix-shell -p mesa freeglut`.

For `stack` users stumbling upon this answer, add this to `~/.stack/stack.yaml`:

```
nix:
  enable: true
  packages: [mesa freeglut]
```

The `nix-shell` solution doesn't work in this case -- the problem, as I'm guessing, is that Stack always works inside a pure environment even if run from inside a `nix-shell`. I did try `pure: false` in the `nix` section of `stack.yaml`, but that didn't work. This does, for now.

- `mesa` is required to provide the C headers for `OpenGLRaw` and other libraries (and this is why linking fails in your case, I believe).
- `freeglut` provides the GLUT bindings (you'll get the "unknown GLUT entry" error otherwise) required at runtime.

You may need to change the `mesa` there to something else, like `mesa_glu`.

Comment: uh, he's using cabal, not stack.

Comment: @Vektorweg thanks for pointing that out! I've modified the instructions; hopefully they'll work in their case (although I don't use `cabal` and can't be sure).

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help, @Soham Chowdhury! Alas, I've tried all combinations of `mesa`, `mesa+freeglut`, `mesa_glu+freeglut` etc. neither works. I believe, the problem is not with `stack` or `cabal`, probably, something is not set properly in my OS environments or configuarions. Does anyone know whether there is something like `glxgears` to see if OpenGL works at all? I couldn't find it in NixOs packages list.

Comment: Yeah, the `stack` really did solve the problem! Farewell, `cabal`, I will miss you :)

Comment: Yeah! *small jump of joy* I haven't used Haskell long enough to have known `cabal` nontrivially, so ... welcome to the dark side? ;)

Comment: Any idea why `nix-shell -p mesa mesa_glu freeglut` doesn't work?

Comment: I think now you have to change those packages to `[libGL libGLU freeglut]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following helped me:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "dev-env";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    mesa
    freeglut
  ];
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH = with pkgs; "${freeglut}/lib";
}
```

Copy this to `shell.nix`, enter the environment with `nix-shell` and run compiled executable inside the env.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason having freeglut in buildInputs is not enough and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is needed.