# nixOS + Haskell + stack + OpenGL + freeglut

Tags: haskell, opengl, haskell-stack, freeglut, nixos

I have read [NixOS, Haskell, opengl : problems with building and running openGL programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527061/nixos-haskell-opengl-problems-with-building-and-running-opengl-programs) and all the other corresponding issues, but I can't get a simple Haskell gloss project (that used to work a few months ago) to work.

### Using a github project

Try the following:

```
$ git clone https://www.github.com/turion/rhine
$ cd rhine/
$ cd rhine-gloss/
$ stack build
$ stack exec rhine-gloss-gears 
freeglut (rhine-gloss-gears):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
```

This project uses the stack nix integration as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588628/562583), but since `mesa` has been renamed recently, the relevant part in `stack.yaml` is now:

```
nix:
  enable: true
  packages: [libGL libGLU freeglut]
```

### From scratch

Make sure you have cabal, stack and nix installed. Then follow these commands:

```
$ mkdir tempgloss
$ cd tempgloss
```

Create two files with these contents:

```
$ cat Main.hs 
import Graphics.Gloss
main = display (InWindow "Nice Window" (200, 200) (10, 10)) white (Circle 80)

$ cat stack.yaml 
resolver: lts-12.10
nix:
  enable: true
  packages: [libGL libGLU freeglut]
```

Now execute:

```
$ cabal init --is-executable -n --main-is=Main.hs -d gloss -d base -l MIT
[...]
$ stack build
[...]
$ stack exec tempgloss
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I'd do it step by step, since there are so many abstractions at play here. Can you run some OGL diag and verify that the OpenGL actually works (with e.g. `glxgears`)? Once you confirm that, try running a freeglut example. Once that works, move to Haskell. Well, that's what I'd do, anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, I don't code in C.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, `glxgears` works as expected. (Installed as a package, not compiled from source)

Comment: Doesn't matter how it's installed, if it works at least your driver/device is fine. Next step would be freeglut; again, I'd recommend building some simple test program [like this one](https://www.badprog.com/c-opengl-checking-the-freeglut-glew-and-opengl-version) and running it.

Comment: Are you using NixOS or Nix with some other distribution? If you are using Nix with some other distribution, you can't really run things, that are hardware accelerated, without some hackery. (Nix tries to bring its own graphics driver, which isn't compatible with your kernel and or X server).

Comment: @Krom, NixOS. But that's also interesting to know. How would someone with nix on a different distribution solve this?

Comment: Please include enough information in the question itself (not offsite resources) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You can use http://github.com/guibou/nixGL to run any nix OpenGL application on a distribution which is not nixos.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I'm trying, but I'm running into (separate) stack problems right now, see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4322.

Comment: @DanielWagner, now I have a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

(This solution is deprecated in favor of my other solution which uses `nixGL`)

The issue is that `stack` is overriding the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of your nixos installation. by default it contains something such as `/run/opengl-driver/lib:/run/opengl-driver-32/lib` and it is override by stack with the path to the library provided by stack, for me it contains: `/nix/store/v1d3fmjjqzd1wh84w8dmy4i3hxzgaybf-libGL-1.0.0/lib:/nix/store/y9s4bbn6j54flhpggccrmjd7cv3nkw60-glu-9.0.0/lib:/nix/store/jx7018a4yvd0x79qwp8ad15h5isy1ny3-freeglut-3.0.0/lib:/nix/store/5z8gx1bjw5s0q96n191k0a8caqr4r580-ghc-8.4.3/lib:/nix/store/yypprmw8hrmvwyhhz23w8z25yjvdhnxb-git-2.18.0/lib:/nix/store/iw94llkj05wgaz268mlzvgx8jkbi1ss0-gcc-wrapper-7.3.0/lib:/nix/store/rxaclc3vhxbzgfllv7601i85z854h48a-gmp-6.1.2/lib`

I don't have an easy solution, that's actually painful that stack does not change the `rpath` of your binary and instead override `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

My quick and dirty solution:

- a) Get the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from inside stack:

`stack exec -- env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nix/store/v1d3fmjjqzd1wh84w8dmy4i3hxzgaybf-libGL-1.0.0/lib:/nix/store/y9s4bbn6j54flhpggccrmjd7cv3nkw60-glu-9.0.0/lib:/nix/store/jx7018a4yvd0x79qwp8ad15h5isy1ny3-freeglut-3.0.0/lib:/nix/store/5z8gx1bjw5s0q96n191k0a8caqr4r580-ghc-8.4.3/lib:/nix/store/yypprmw8hrmvwyhhz23w8z25yjvdhnxb-git-2.18.0/lib:/nix/store/iw94llkj05wgaz268mlzvgx8jkbi1ss0-gcc-wrapper-7.3.0/lib:/nix/store/rxaclc3vhxbzgfllv7601i85z854h48a-gmp-6.1.2/lib`

- b) get your current `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

`$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/run/opengl-driver/lib:/run/opengl-driver-32/lib`

- c) get the real path of your executable

`$ stack exec --no-nix-pure which rhine-gloss-gears
/tmp/rhine/rhine-gloss/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/nightly-2018-09-26/8.4.3/bin/rhine-gloss-gears`

here, `--no-nix-pure` allows `stack` to see `which` which should be available in your current environment.

d) concatenate all of that, using:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=yourLD_LIBRARY_PATH:theOneFromStack the_executable_path`

Exemple:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/run/opengl-driver/lib:/run/opengl-driver-32/lib:/nix/store/v1d3fmjjqzd1wh84w8dmy4i3hxzgaybf-libGL-1.0.0/lib:/nix/store/y9s4bbn6j54flhpggccrmjd7cv3nkw60-glu-9.0.0/lib:/nix/store/jx7018a4yvd0x79qwp8ad15h5isy1ny3-freeglut-3.0.0/lib:/nix/store/5z8gx1bjw5s0q96n191k0a8caqr4r580-ghc-8.4.3/lib:/nix/store/yypprmw8hrmvwyhhz23w8z25yjvdhnxb-git-2.18.0/lib:/nix/store/iw94llkj05wgaz268mlzvgx8jkbi1ss0-gcc-wrapper-7.3.0/lib:/nix/store/rxaclc3vhxbzgfllv7601i85z854h48a-gmp-6.1.2/lib /tmp/rhine/rhine-gloss/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/nightly-2018-09-26/8.4.3/bin/rhine-gloss-gears`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just pushed a new version of `nixGL`: http://github.com/guibou/nixgl` which allows you to run your program as:

`stack exec --no-nix-pure nixGLIntel rhine-gloss-gears`

(replace `nixGLIntel` by `nixGLNvidia` or `nixGLNvidiaBumblebee` if needed).

Comment: Why is nixGL not part of nixpkgs? Or rather, why isn't the fix from nixGL in nixpkgs?

Comment: Well, I should definitely submit it as a `nixpkgs` package. However that's not trivial to fix everything because it depends on the hardware AND the version of `nixpkgs` an application is built with. For example, if you have a clone of `nixpkgs` from last week and a nvidia driver, you'll need a different build of `nixGL` than me, who use a more recent clone of `nixpkgs` and an intel driver.